# Send Value to client and and pop modal with stuff refering to the value

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask, jinja2

im a first year student in IT and we are doing at school database management we need to do the SCRUD on the database. I would like to go a bit futher away with one specialty but i can't make it work after many many hours of trying and researching. In my data table i have 3 icons.

**What i want to do :
On click on the information icon, i would like to show more data concerning only this person. To display the data, a modal will pop up with it. Then when click outside the modal and checking another costumer, i would like it display "live" the data for this client.**

Our tools : 
We are using VSC, Python, Flask, Jinja, Javascrip, html, css(bootstrap)

**Here is what i've tried and got done so far :**

On click the data is correctly send to the server side and well returned, (when i'll go on the developper tools /network , i can see my result poping. The problem is i can't make it comes "live" on my page with the modal.

For now on im just trying to pass a variable for test purpose, later on, i will send back some SQL queries. I guess it  will be the best to use render_template_string since i would like to display a modal with all the informations refreshed ?

Screens : 
[screen of my data table](https://ibb.co/NLbHSxT/)
[modal pop up](https://ibb.co/ypW85nC/)
[network response](https://ibb.co/yQqmTqk/)
[console log](https://ibb.co/7pJFv7Y/)

Here is my Python :

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
    getIdClient =None
    if request.method == "POST":
        getIdClient = request.json
        idClientGetted = json.dumps(getIdClient) ## transferring the value
        return render_template('EditCampagne.html', idClientGetted = idClientGetted)
```

Here is my Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.showValue').bind('click', function() {
    var getIdClient = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].textContent; // getting the value of the client id in the table
    var showIt =  document.getElementById('inputCache'); //temporary value, just to make it appears on the html for more visiblity
    showIt.value = getIdClient;
    console.log(getIdClient);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test',
        type: "POST",
        datatype:'json',
        contentType:'application/json',
        data:JSON.stringify(getIdClient) 
  }) /* verification data sent correctly */
  .done(function (data) { console.log("Envoyé " + getIdClient) }) 
  .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log("ERROR"); });
```

Here is my html for  the data table

Résultat : {{ idClientGetted }}

```
        <form method="POST" action="">

        <div>

        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="row"></div>
          <div class="col-3 m-auto">
            <div class="input-group mb-2">  
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInputCamp" onkeyup="searchThruTable()" placeholder="Rechercher">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10 m-auto pt-5">
          <table id="mytable3" class="table font-weight-normal ">
              <thead class="bg-primary text-white rounded font-weight-normal">
                  <tr style="font-size:14px;">
                      <th># Client</th>                      
                      <th>Nom</th>
                      <th>Prénom</th> <!-- pour plus tard essayer de fusionner le champs prenom + nom -->
                      <th>Compagnie</th>
                      <th>Nombres de campagnes</th><!-- pour plus tard essayer de fusionner le champs adresse total -->
                      <th>Nombres d'objectif</th>
                      <th>Budget</th>
                      <th>Cout total Obj</th> 
                      <th>Bénéfice</th>
                      <th>Apport Privé</th>                      
                      <th><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></th>
                      <th><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></th>
                      <th><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></th>                            
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              {% for row in dataCampV %}
                  <tr style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;">           
                      <th scope="row">{{ row.id_Client }}</th>
                      <td>{{ row.Nom }}</td>
                      <td>{{ row.Prenom }}</td>
                      <td>{{ row.Nom_Entreprise }}</td>
                      <td>{{ row.qtecamp }}</td>
                      <td>{{ row.qteobj }}</td>
                      <td>{{ row.budgettot }}</td>
                      <td>{{ row.couttotalobj }}</td>
                      <td>{{ row.bnf }}</td>
                      <td>{{ row.apportprive }}</td>                
                      <td class="text-center"><a href="#showClientModalInfo" data-toggle="modal" class="setCellValue showValue"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></a></td>
                      <td class="text-center"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></td>
                      <td class="text-center"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></td>
                  </tr>
              {% endfor %}
          </table>
          </form>
      </div>
```

here is my html for the modal ( with screen)

```
   <div class="modal fade " id="showClientModalInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="clientLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="clientLabel">Numéro Client : {{ idClientGetted }}</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-11 m-auto text-left">
                    <table id="modalTable" class="table font-weight-normal">                               
                        <tr>
                          <td style="border-top:0px;font-weight:600;">Numéro de campagne : </td> 
                          <td style="border-top:0px;font-weight:600;">###</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Budget  : </td> 
                          <td>##</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Bénéfice : </td> 
                          <td>###</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr>                                                                                       
                        <tr>
                          <td>Date d'échéance : </td> 
                          <td>###</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr>                                                                                   
                        <tr>
                          <td>Apport Privé : </td> 
                          <td>###</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr> 

                        <tr>
                          <td style="border-top:0px;"></td>
                          <td style="border-top:0px;"></td> 
                          </tr>                                                                                  
                        <tr>
                          <td style="border-top:0px; font-weight:600;">Numéro d'objectif : </td> 
                          <td style="border-top:0px;font-weight:600;">###</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Type : </td> 
                          <td>###</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Plateforme  : </td> 
                          <td>###</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Cout objectif : </td> 
                          <td>###</td>                                                                                                                       
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Devise : </td>
                          <td>###</td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Coût par clique  : </td> 
                          <td>###</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Coût par acquisition  : </td> 
                          <td>###</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr>
                        <!-- rajouter dans la query si null écrire autre chose-->
                        <tr>
                          <td>Nombre d'impression  : </td> 
                          <td>###</td>                                                                                        
                        </tr>                
                      </table> 
                    </div>
                  </div>                          
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fermer</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Imprimer la fiche client</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**My end goal : 
I would like to make the modal appears dynamically without having to refresh the page or load another one.**

If you could give me some ints it would be really nice ! Still everything mixwed up with all theses news languages and features :)

Thanks everyone for the time you took to read my questions.

Comment: don't do too much, make a static page, show a modal use hard-coded variable, only if this work then see do you have other problem.

Comment: I was thinking to do it aswell, but i really wanted to make it work, since i've spent so many hours trying things.

It cames to my mind now, if in my first block i'll creat a promise, and use an asynch function with the await for showing the modal, should it work ?